# android recyclerview image not adjusting

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview

I have few imageviews in the recyclerviews which doesnot stretvh to the height and width specified to it in xml.I also want gap between items of recyclerview so I have set layout_marginTop to 10dp in the relativelayout but even that is not working.Below is the xml code of recyclerview.

```
recyclerlayout.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:background="#b000"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Android"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="Kochi"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:src="@drawable/marker" />
        <!--android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"-->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity.xml:(Only recyclerview included)

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                >
```

As you can see in the screenshot the layout didn't display as expected.

[image]

Comment: Add Padding "10" to main RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

Comment: I tried the snippet you posted but now the image has moved to the left and now there is a gap on the right

Comment: use centreCrop instead of fitStart. Note: this may crop the boundaries of your images in order to maintain the aspect ratio of the image

Answer (score 0):

You r problems may to be because you have not setted alignment for all views, add to every `android:above` or/and `android:below` with id of specific view as value.

You can also try to wrap all Views into vertical `LinearLayout`, which would be a child of `RelativeLayout`.

After that add:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```